# PostgreSQL Alter column from array of varchar to array of pair(varchar, integer)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, alter

Now I have a array of varchar (nullable & no default value),
and wanting to convert it into a array of pair(varchar, integer).
For the integer value, just set 0 for now.

For example, `["a", "b"]` will be `[("a", 0), ("b", 0)]`.

I already know that I can create pair type via:

```
CREATE TYPE keycount AS (key VARCHAR, count INTEGER);
```

but have no idea how to use `SET` to alter the column.

Thank you for any advices!

Comment: I'm confused. how does an varchar[], get to (varchar,int)... What do you fill the int in with?

Comment: I guess you can't convert the column directly (via `ALTER`). You need to create a new column first (of `keycount` type), then copy data from old to new column, and then delete the old column.

Comment: Hello @EvanCarroll, I'd like to fill it with 0 as edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First create the type

```
CREATE TYPE keycount AS (key VARCHAR, count INTEGER);
```

Now you need to create the casts..

```
CREATE FUNCTION text_to_keycount(a text)
RETURNS keycount AS
$$
  SELECT ($1, 0)::keycount
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE CAST (text AS keycount) WITH FUNCTION text_to_keycount(text);

SELECT ARRAY['asdf','asdf']::text[]::keycount[];
```

Now you can create the table and cast the type `USING`

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a text[] );
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES
  ( ARRAY['1','2','3'] );
ALTER TABLE foo
  ALTER COLUMN a
    SET DATA TYPE keycount[]
    USING CAST (a AS keycount[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the rows in the keycount column have valid data, i.e there aren't any rows that are like '{"abc", ""}', then the following would work. If there are any invalid data in the column, then that has to be first cleaned, before changing the column type.

The trick is to create a temporary pair column populate it with data, delete the old column & rename the temporary column back to the original.

This is needed because there is no way for Postgresql to figure out how to convert between a VARCHAR[] to a keycount automatically.

example:

```
-- setup a test table
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE test (col VARCHAR[]);
INSERT INTO test (col) VALUES ('{"abc", "1"}'::varchar[]);
SELECT col FROM test;
-- returns {abc,1}
CREATE TYPE keycount AS (key VARCHAR, count INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN col2 keycount;
UPDATE test SET col2 = (col[1], col[2]::int)::keycount;
ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN col;
ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN col2 TO col;
SELECT col FROM test;
-- returns (abc,1)
COMMIT;
```

**EDIT**

The above isn't required. Although it works, it is overly complicated.

It is possible to specify the type cast in the alter statement via a [USING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) clause:

Utilizing this clause in the ALTER statement

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN col TYPE keycount USING (col[1], col[2]::INTEGER)::keycount;
```

There's no need to *stage* the data & drop & rename.

Comment: Hello @haleemur, I want to transfer the array into array of keycount, thank you still!

Comment: the answer above doesn't tackle that, but it _should_ give you enough clues to achieve what you're looking for. if you still have issues, please update your post with what you've tried, and we can take it from there.